# RF ignition in metal halide lamps

Tags: radio-frequency

We know that metal halide lamps and other HID lamps (like xenon/mercury arc ones) require 2-30kV+ spark to initiate discharge. Handling these voltages is not easy, and I am thinking if it's possible to initiate discharge by applying radiofrequency on the electrodes (for example 13.56 MHz) for a short time, just like in induction lamps or plasma etching chambers?

How does required power depend on gas pressure? Do I just need higher amplitude to excite high-pressure lamp or it's just impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ignition of such discharge lamps is done by "high" frequency 
since long. But using 13.565 MHz for that is nonsense, because You 
invite a lot of short-wave problems without any profit. 
The ignition works at frequencies from some kHz to some dozen kHz. 
Gas pressure: only Xenon high pressure lamps have really high (some bars) 
pressure before start. All other lamps have not more than some 
millibars or less.

And: Power/pressure is a question of someone lacking simplest gas 
discharge basics. To ignite You need a voltage, and after that 
some current, µA or in extreme cases some milliamperes are sufficient.
The main voltage source takes over and drives the lamp warm 
within some seconds or minutes.

Generally: Why do You try to reinvent wheels? The mere fact that 
millions of discharge lamps are around in the world says that ignition 
has been solved in some way.

Comment: 13.56Mhz is a standard frequency for industrial applications, so RF emission should not be a (big) problem there. Am I missing something, but I had an impression that most of these lamps use dumb electrical brakedown during a single peak. Going for brakedown in 'cold state' is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I want to reinvent the wheel because this should be more economical, reliable and safer. Electronics for 2kV+ is just too complex & expensive.

Comment: ""because this should be more economical, reliable and safer."" Aha, I see You will be/are a real engineer: "I have a solution! Where is the problem?" ""Electronics for 2kV+ is just too complex" shows You do not have knowledge of electronics. I recommend anpother time to inform You on "state of the art" before You try to invent better things.

Comment: This is not for job, this is for hobby. Hence, I don't have many 'production' limitations. I just want to avoid high voltage here and that's it. If majority of industry uses different approach - that's fine with me, but this still is not what I am trying to achive.

Comment: Still not a good aproach, it seems You want to replace frequency for voltage, what makes You think that this works?

Comment: If you put 27Mhz radio transmitter antenna next to gas discharge lamp, it will glow, but there is no 100-200V needed to light it usual way.

Comment: What is the ignition voltage of that lamp? The world is not as simply mended as You seem to think.

Comment: Well, gas discharge lamp is hard to light with cold electrodes using the same brakedown due to low electron emission (same issue we have in metal halide lamps, but distance between electrodes is much larger). Anyway, it's still > 100V even with hot electrodes.

Comment: Why do You conjecture? Just look for the ignition voltage  of a glow lamp. Wiki "glow lamp".

Comment: It is ~100 for hot electrodes, and more for cold. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp

Comment: 1st this is wrong, second I did not talk about fluorescent lamps. I give up.

Comment: Figures I've found for neon lamps are 66-200V, still the same range.